# How to match json response in 2 requests?

Tags: json, jmeter, compare

I have a json response in 1 request like this:

> {"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"id":1034,"item_type_val":"Business
>   Requirement","field_name":"Assigned To","invalid_value":"Jmeter
>   System","dep_value":"","dep_field":""},{"id":1033,"item_type_val":"Risk","field_name":"Category","invalid_value":"Energy","dep_value":"Logged
>   User","dep_field":"Assigned To"}]}

and in 2nd request like this:

> {"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"id":1100,"item_type_val":"Business
>   Requirement","field_name":"Assigned To","invalid_value":"Jmeter
>   System","dep_value":"","dep_field":""},{"id":1111,"item_type_val":"Risk","field_name":"Category","invalid_value":"Energy","dep_value":"Logged
>   User","dep_field":"Assigned To"}]}

Both are same but different id's. I need to verify the 1st json response from 2nd json response and compare both that both are same or not. here both are same but having different id's which should be acceptable. how can i do this by regex so i can ignore the id's and match whole content?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it with a single regex but other way out is you can create a map of it and then compare everything except 'id'

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you please suggest that how can i create a map for it in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way would be just discarding these `id` entries using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language which comes with [JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the sampler, which returns your JSON
2. Put the following code into the JSR223 PostProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
   def jsonResponse = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
   jsonResponse.rows.findAll { it.remove("id") }
   def newResponse = new JsonBuilder(jsonResponse).toPrettyString()
   //depending on what you need
   vars.put("responseWithoutId", newResponse)    // store response withou ID into a JMeter Variable
   prev.setResponseData(new String(newResponse)) // overwrite parent sampler response data
   log.info(newResponse)                         // just print the new value to jmeter.log file
   ```

[image: JSR223 JSON]

So you have the following choices:

1. `vars.put("responseWithoutId", newResponse)` - stores the new JSON (without these `id`) into a `${responseWithoutId}` JMeter Variable
2. `prev.setResponseData(new String(newResponse))` - after this line execution parent sampler data won't contain any "id"
3. `log.info(newResponse)` - just prints JSON without "id" to *jmeter.log* file

I don't know your test plan design, personally I would store responses from 2 requests into 2 different JMeter Variables i.e. `${response1}` and `${response2}` using above approach and compare them with the [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) like:

[image: Response Assertion]